# Send Rest call in a loop

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I have a Rest API that in order to get the end data AKA:ENDDATA I need to send few requests (depends how deep). So when sending the first request the return response will have in the body the nextUri and so on…

Basically I need to execute a list of Rest calls based on the nextUri till I reach to the end ENDDATA.

Is there a preferred way to do this with React & Redux\redux-thunk.

```
export const find = () => dispatch => {
dispatch({ type: FIND_CUSTOMER_START });

axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: '/v1/...',
    headers: { 'X': 'XXX1' },
    auth: {
        username: 'XXX1',
        password: 'XXX'
    },
    data: 'SELECT * FROM .....'
}).then(function (response) {
    // Need to find the nextUri ... before update teh state
    dispatch({
        type: SUCCESS,
        payload: response.data
    });
}).catch(function (error) {
    dispatch({ type: ERROR, payload: error });
 });
 }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Define your api call in a redux action

Inside a component lifecycle method you can call this action. As well as map the state from the store to your component.

When the action updates the state it will cause a re-render and call the lifecycle method. In the lifecycle method you can check to see if `ENDDATA` is true and if not call the action again.

Inside render you can have the same conditional as in the lifecycle method and have it return a spinner to indicate loading.

Comment: Thank you Greg for the answer. Can you please add some code example to see how would you handle this with React hooks during the component life cycle.

Comment: For sure. I actually have to do something similar today so I'll post an example in a little bit :)